# IBM ServeRAID bad stripes and synchronize

Tags: windows-server-2003, chkdsk, bad-blocks, ibm

After one of the drives in our IBM RAID gone, we bought a new one and replaced it.

The rebuilding went fine, but now we see "Bad stripes" reported for the logical disk.
Moreover, some data can not be read from the disk, and ServeRAID reports bad blocks.

CHKDSK just hangs on 22% of reading, closing it and re-running jumps to the 22% again.

Question - is it possible to resolve this situation by synchronizing the logical drive?
Or it better leave the CHKDSK running until it hopefully completes?

Also, what the synchronization actually does and can it heal bad stripes?

The server model is x3400, RAID is ServeRAID 8k-l.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a solid answer for you, but my advice would be to contact IBM; support is one of the reasons you pay a premium for good server hardware. Also - You haven't said what model of server and RAID controller you have, that will probably make a difference for the answer as well.

Comment: Correct - question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the new hard disk isn't "DOA"?

Comment: The disk is fine, the rebuild completed successfully. According to IBM, disks can be re-built and still considered with bad stripes - i.e. contain bad blocks.

Comment: I think you should get some answers from IBM. Maybe there's more than one faulty hard disk, or your RAID card is causing corruption. Your trouble wasn't caused by a single faulty disk.

Comment: It seems BOTH disks became faulty at same time - just our luck it seems...

Comment: Welcome to RAID5 hell :-)

Comment: RAID1 actually, but that was hell indeed :).